# SQL table where clause error

Tags: mysql, sql

i need the LAST_NAME, JOB_ID, SALARY columns from table workers and the job id needs to be SH_CLERK or SA_REP and the SALARY column CANNOT equal to 1000,2600,3000,7000,8000 or 9000

```
SELECT `LAST_NAME`, `JOB_ID`, `SALARY` FROM `workers`
WHERE `JOB_ID` = SH_CLERK OR SA_REP AND `SALARY` != 1000 and 2600 and 3000 and 7000 and 8000 and 9000;
```

i dont know whats wrong, i get the  #1054 - Unknown column 'SH_CLERK' in 'where clause' error.

Thanks !

Comment: What is the data type of JOB_ID?  Is it a key to another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around strings.

Switch multiple `OR`'s to using `IN` instead.

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, JOB_ID, SALARY
  FROM workers
 WHERE JOB_ID IN ('SH_CLERK', 'SA_REP')
   AND SALARY NOT IN (1000, 2600, 3000, 7000, 8000, 9000);
```

Comment: SELECT `LAST_NAME`, `JOB_ID`, `SALARY` FROM `inimesed` WHERE `JOB_ID` = `SH_CLERK` or `SA_REP` AND `SALARY` != `1000` and `2600` and `3000` and `7000` and `8000` and `9000`;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, JOB_ID, SALARY
FROM workers
WHERE  JOB_ID IN ('SH_CLERK', 'SA_REP') AND
   SALARY NOT IN (1000, 2600, 3000, 7000,8000, 9000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if I understand the problem correctly,
If `job_id` is a number data and SH_CLERK or SA_REP is taken from other table.

```
`Select last_name, job_id, salary 
 from workers 
 where job_id = (select id from <user table> 
                 where <sh_clerk/sa_rep column name field> like 'SH_CLERK' or 
                       <sh_clerk/sa_rep column name field> like 'SA_REP')
 and SALARY not in(1000, 2600, 3000, 7000, 8000, 9000);`
```

`<user table>` is the table where SH_CLERK or SA_REP taken from

`<sh_clerk/sa_rep column name field>` is the column name in the `<user table>`